# What is the highest allowed price for an android in app billing items?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I got one simple question...

What is the highest allowed price for a single android in app billing item?

I found the following link: http://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/bin/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=138412

But the prices listed there, are just for a single app, not for in app billing.

For in app billing I found this page: http://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1153485

But there is no answer to my question :( So I ask you...

Currently I got no developer account for the google market, so I can't try it out. I also contacted the google support about 3 days ago, but got no answer yet :(

I really hope, you can help me :)

Comment: Anyone else got an answer, since blackbelt isn't really sure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as far as I know the max allowed price is 100 euro

edit: just to be clear.. once I tried to upload an apk with more than 100 euro as price and market rejected it.

Edit: since 2013 looks like Google pushed the maximum to 200 euros

Comment: So the maximum price of an in app billing item is the same, like the price for a single app? E.g. I could upload my app for a price of 100€ and then sell 3 in app items for 100€ each?

Comment: I think yes.. but for sure why don't send an email to the google support asking for it?

Comment: As I wrote in my question above: "I also contacted the google support about 3 days ago, but got no answer yet :("

Comment: is that answer referring to in app billing, or simply to app price?

Comment: I pick this as an answer, even if you are not sure about it... But theres no one else, answering my question :(

Comment: In app products price ranges are upto 200 euros

Comment: @kumarc the answer is old 18 months. Things could have changed in the meanwhile

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it 200$ or equivalent in the local currency? That is how much you can set for default price in google play developer console.

Answer (score 0):

To provide an update to this answer:

The maximum price increased in 2015 to 350 EUR or 400 USD, valid for both App-price and In-App-Price